Export members of all groups in Teams and sharepoints listing
I hope you are well!
I'm new to learning Office 365, to be honest, this is the first time I'm using it.
I have two very specific demands:
1 - Export all members of all Teams groups and their respective sharepoints
2 - Export all sharepoints and the people who have access to them.
I imagine I will need to use powershell. Could you help me with the necessary instructions to obtain this data in .CSV.
Thank you in advance!
An example of the data I would like to obtain is:
1-
Group name in Teams / Participants / Teams Sharepoint
2-
Sharepoint name / Participants (people with access)
